# How to add internet speed meter in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, command-line, 16.04, 22.04, ubuntu-drivers

I read so many articles and steps for doing it. I have a doubt that doing that steps will bring virus to my ubuntu.can you please guide me how to install internet speed meter in 100% secure way

Comment: Please be more specific. What is the exact name (package name, website etc.) of what you're trying to install? "Speed meter" is ambiguous.

Comment: Maybe you don't need anything installed. A basic internet speed test can run in a browser and you get the ping, download and upload speed.
Just try one of these: - https://www.speedtest.net/ - https://fast.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is a GNOME Shell Extension called "Net Speed Simplified" wich will show you your internet speed.

You can simply install it from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3724/net-speed-simplified/).

Hope this helps!